# Маленький вопрос по сортировке по элементу в массиве

Tags: perl

Всем привет.
Есть строка из файла:

```
значение0|значение1|значение2|
```

Мне нужно отсортировать по значение1 в котором дата 01.01.18, делаю так:

```
@array = sort { [split /\|/, $a]->[1] cmp [split /\|/, $b]->[1] } @array;
```

проблем нет.
Теперь нужно по другому, отсортировать по значение2, а в нем список дат: 
|11.11.2011,12.11.2011,13.11.2011|, сортировать нужно только по первой дате из списка.
Помогите модифицировать строчку сортировки, что то не догоняю.
Спасибо!

Comment: А вас точно устраивает текущая сортировка значения1 ? ведь `20.12.17`  больше чем `01.01.18` ... Я бы первую дату из 2 значения получал как то так `join '', reverse split(/\./, [$_[0]=~/(?:.*?\|){2}(.*?)[,|]/]->[0])` (заодно разворачивая задом наперед для правильной сортировки по дате)

Comment: Не понял почему для правильной сортировки нужно разворачивать. Вроде и так работает.

Comment: вы попробуйте разные месяца и разные года. там же строковое сравнение. А строки сравнивают слева на право. 30 число любого месяца будет больше чем 20 любого другого, даже если месяц и год больше

Answer (score 0):

Получилось так:

```
sort { substr([split /\|/, $a]->[2],0,10) cmp substr([split /\|/, $b]->[2],0,10) }
```